# Linux tail + grep + less

Tags: linux, grep, feed, tail, less-unix

I want to see live output from my website's access log. I want to see only certail types of entries, in this case, entries that match ".php".

This works fine, but lines wrap to the next line and I don't want that:

```
tail -f access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered
```

This works fine for avoiding the line wrapping, but it is not filtered:

```
less +F -S access-log
```

I prefer looking at the file without lines wrapping to the next line because it is easier to see the structure in the output, this is what I want `less -S` for.

This kind of works, but the "cursor" doesn't stay at the bottom of the file, and any command I enter makes `less` hang (press "SHIFT + f" for staying at the bottom as the stream comes):

```
tail -f access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered | less -S
```

But this doesn't work at all:

```
tail -f access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered | less +F -S
```

So, is there a way to achieve the what I want?

I also take outside-the-box solutions, maybe cutting with `sed` so that each line is never longer than my screen?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: sorry about that, I thought this looked more like a script and less like configuration of linux. I could achieve the same thing with PHP or any other language

Comment: It's not configuration, it's just ordinary use of command line tools. Admittedly there's a fuzzy line between complex command lines and scripting. But a good rule of thumb (IMO) is that if it's a one-liner with no variables, it's not really scripting.

Comment: you are certainly right, this is why I upvoted your comment. I wouldn't mind of someone more savvy than me moved this question to another stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash I suggest:

```
tail -f access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

Comment: perfect, thank you :)... although, it would be pretty good if there was a way to make less to the job too, what if I want to save the output or scroll up or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `watch` command:

`watch -n1 tail access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered`

Comment: can you please explain what this does? I have only used watch for things like `ls -hal` where I need to monitor the change in size of the files, etc.

Comment: This command will monitor live errors in `access-log` with refresh interval `1s`

Answer (score 0):

I already used the accepted answer for my case, but I guess if I really wanted to use less because I like other features it also offers, I could do this:

```
tail -f access-log | fgrep ".php" --line-buffered >> tmp.access-log
```

And then

```
less -S +F tmp.access-log
```

Then when I am done, if I don't need that tmp file I just delete it.